# Login and registration form using servlets and app engine data store

Tags: google-app-engine, servlets

I am new to servlets and app engine data store. I tried creating a simple login and registration form using servlets and I stored the new user in the app engine data store from the registration form servlet.
But I have no idea of how to check whether the user name and password given by the user at the time of login matches the data store entry. Can anyone help me out in this??

Login Servlet:

```
public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {

    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException {
        res.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = res.getWriter();

        String user = req.getParameter("usern");
        String password = req.getParameter("psd");

        HttpSession s = req.getSession();
        s.setAttribute("usernm", user);

        if ((user.equalsIgnoreCase(????) && password.equalsIgnoreCase(????))) {
            req.getRequestDispatcher("/profile").include(req, res);
        } else {
            out.print("Sorry UserName or Password Error!");
            req.getRequestDispatcher("/index.html").forward(req, res);

        }

    }
```

Registration Servlet:

```
public class RegistrationServlet extends HttpServlet {

public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException {

        res.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = res.getWriter();

        String n = req.getParameter("userName");
        String p = req.getParameter("userPass");
        String c = req.getParameter("confirmPass");
        String e = req.getParameter("userEmail");

        if (!c.equals(p)) {
            out.println("<h3>Enter correct password</h3>");
            req.getRequestDispatcher("register.html").forward(req, res);
        } else {

            Entity u = new Entity("User", e);
            u.setProperty("userName", n);
            u.setProperty("passWord", p);
            u.setProperty("userEmail", e);
            DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
            datastore.put(u);

            u.getKey().getName();
            com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Key k = KeyFactory.createKey("User", e);

            out.println("<h3>Successfully registered</h3>");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you add some code of what you've tried so far?

Comment: added my code sample.. Can you check that and tell me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can retrieve the user entity with a query using the username of the user and then check if the given password matches the user's password:

```
String user = req.getParameter("usern");
String password = req.getParameter("psd");
Query q =  new Query("User")
    .setFilter(new FilterPredicate("userName", FilterOperator.EQUAL, user));
PreparedQuery pq = datastore.prepare(q);
Entity storedUser = pq.asSingleEntity();
String storedPassword = (String) storedUser.getProperty("passWord");
if (storedPassword.equals(password)) { 
  //correct password
}
```

You can find more info on working with Google Cloud Datastore in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/datastore/creating-entities)

Comment: Thank you so much...I can now login using the information from the data base

Comment: You're welcome, I'd advise you to hash the password before storing it for security reasons

Comment: Can you explain me in detail how to do that?

Comment: I m getting an error :HTTP ERROR 500
Problem accessing /login. Reason: INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR

Comment: @HariniSampath Hashing is a whole new topic entirely, better post a new SO question for that. Can you post the stacktrace for the error you're getting?